# Filter a list without making a new list?

Tags: python

So I'm working on a project where I have a list of objects. I would like to filter the list based on an object attribute, but since this list is used in many other places in my code, I can't create a new list as it will create problems elsewhere in my codes.

I have tried to use this:

```
individuals = list(filter(lambda x: x.waterstore > 0, individuals))
```

but it gives me "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'individuals' referenced before assignment".

Here is the code where the problem occurs.

```
def day(numberOfDays):
   days = 0
   while days < numberOfDays:
       print(str(days) + " days")
       child = randint(1,100)
       if child > 95:
           IndividualGenerator(randint(1,2))
       SeekWaterHole(individuals, lakes)
       rain(lakes)
       DrinkWater(individuals, lakes)
       for r in range(len(individuals)):
           individuals[r].waterstore -= 1
       individuals = list(filter(lambda x: x.waterstore > 0,individuals))
       individualTotalWater = []
       for i in individuals:
           individualTotalWater.append(i.waterstore)
       AmountWater = lakes[0].water
       Logg = [AmountWater, sum(individualTotalWater), len(individuals)]
       with open("NewCSVTestFile.csv", "a") as f:
               openfile = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
               openfile.writerow(Logg)
       print("logg " + str(Logg))
       print()
       days += 1
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You just have to initialize `individuals` *somewhere*; what do you think `filter` is filtering?

Comment: Where does `individuals` come from for the preceding calls to `SeekWaterHold` and `DrinkWater` and the preceding `for` loop?

Comment: The reason for your `UnboundLocalError` seems to be the call to `SeekWaterHole` on line 8, where you indeed use `individuals` before you assign it in line 13. Note that you do this again in line 10.

Comment: Maybe I did not show enough of the total code, individuals are already a list of objects before def day(NumberOfDays).
Both "SeekWaterHole" and "DrinkWater" works fine until I add individuals = list(filter(lambda x: x.waterstore > 0,individuals))

Comment: if I change to NewListIndividuals = list(filter(lambda x: x.waterstore > 0,individuals))
I do not get UnboundLocalError. I dont understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'individuals' referenced before assignment".

Your first reference to `individuals` occurs here:

```
SeekWaterHole(individuals, lakes)
```

but it is not yet defined in your function, nor given as input to the function. Hence python does not know to what it references.

Comment: ah, now I understand. By adding "global individuals" on top of the code it works! 
'

Comment: This brings up a new question...
Why does the code works fine if I write "NewListIndividuals = list(filter(lambda x: x.waterstore > 0,individuals))?

but I get an error if I write "individuals = list(filter(lambda x: x.waterstore > 0,individuals))"?

In the first case "SeekWaterHole" and "Drinkwater" has no problems, but in the second case, it does. 
I don't understand how "global individuals" would not be necessary in the first case, but necessary in the second.

Comment: See here for `global` keyword in pyhton: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function

Answer (score 0):

you can add individuals[] as an empty list just before the line of error or u can initialize individuals as an global.

```
from random import randint
def day(numberOfDays):
individuals=''
days = 0
while days < numberOfDays:
    print(str(days) + " days")
    child = randint(1,100)
    #if child > 95:
        #IndividualGenerator(randint(1,2))
    individuals=[]//initialize the list before using it
    #SeekWaterHole(individuals, lakes)
    #rain(lakes)
    #DrinkWater(individuals, lakes)
    for r in range(len(individuals)):
        individuals[r].waterstore -= 1
    individuals = list(filter(lambda x: x.waterstore > 0,individuals))
    individualTotalWater = []
    for i in individuals:
        individualTotalWater.append(i.waterstore)
    #AmountWater = lakes[0].water
    #Logg = [AmountWater, sum(individualTotalWater), len(individuals)]
    #with open("NewCSVTestFile.csv", "a") as f:
    #        openfile = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
    #        openfile.writerow(Logg)
    #print("logg " + str(Logg))
    print()
    days += 1
day(10)
```